# My program will not resume audio playback

Tags: java, android, audio, button, playback

i am having difficulty with my app trying to start and stop audio playback.
currently i can get it to start, then stop. but i cannot get it to start again. i am using two buttons to help me. here is my code:

```
public class dnarasol extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.freq);

    Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    play.setOnClickListener(
                  new Button.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                          mp.start();
                     }
                  });
    stop.setOnClickListener(
              new Button.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      mp.stop();
                      mp.release();
                 }
              });
}}
```

Can anyone see where my problem lies? thankyou very much for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call `mp.release()` your player instance is no longer usable.

You should call `mp.release()` in `onDestroy()`. And in your stop handler just leave `stop()`:

```
stop.setOnClickListener(
          new Button.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  mp.stop();
             }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize mp inside the play button.

```
play.setOnClickListener(
                  new Button.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(View v) {
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.freq);
```

`mp.start();
                 }
              });`

Comment: but i need to be able to stop it outside the button event, wont this not allow me to do that?